# Can a batsman be out hit wicket on a no ball, and do runs scored count?

Tags: rules, cricket

A no ball is bowled. The striker hits the ball, but in doing so accidentally puts down their wicket. Will the runs be considered or not? And will be the striker be out hit wicket or not?

Comment: I'm not a huge follower of cricket, so I may have minced some of the terminology in re-wording this question. However, as it stands, it seems like the close vote / downvotes are no longer unnecessary, since it is entirely clear what is being asked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the laws are trivially clear on a no ball, hit wicket.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. [The community consensus is that low-effort is not a reason for closing](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/661/rules-questions-with-little-effort-do-we-close-these-questions-as-off-topic-o/697#697).

Comment: @Nij - I could say the same about 90% of the association football (soccer) questions on here. I had no idea this was the case in cricket - what is obvious to you may not well be obvious to others.

Comment: A lot of football law application requires knowledge of the game in a real context, or implications not actually stated. This is like asking "if an IFK goes straight into the goal, can the team keep playing? Is it a goal?" - to which the only reasonable response is "that's explicitly stated in very simple terms in the laws of the game".

Comment: And no, there isn't a community consensus on low-effort questions. A moderator stated their view and it has total score of 3. That's not at all close to a consensus.

Comment: There were three upvoted answers saying "keep them open" and one downvoted answer saying "close". That's as close as we ever get to a consensus on meta here.

Answer (score 1):

A batsman *cannot* be out hit wicket from a no ball. See [Law 24.16](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-24-no-ball/):

> When No ball has been called, neither batsman shall be out under any of the Laws except 33 (Handled the ball), 34 (Hit the ball twice), 37 (Obstructing the field) or 38 (Run out).

As such, if a batsman does break his own wicket after a no ball, nothing in particular happens: the ball is *not* dead because no wicket has fallen, so any runs scored count as normal.

(This assumes that breaking the wicket was accidental; if it was deliberate, the fielding side may have a case for the batsman being out obstructing the field).